# Grouping with condition AWK

Tags: bash, sorting, loops, awk

Hello I have this text file:

```
chr1      30.3
chrx      30.5
chr3      31.3
chr4      31.7
chrX      33.6
chr1      34.1
```

I would like to get:

```
30 - 31    2
31 - 32    2
32 - 33    0
33 - 34    1
34 - 35    1
```

I am trying to use this bash and awk code, but it doesnt work. Could you help me?

```
#!/bin/bash

for i in {30..60..1}
do
    h=$i

    let "h += 1"

    export i
    export h 

    awk -v g=$i -v c=$h '{if ($3 >= $g && $3< $c) print $0}' /home/filip/Desktop/AMrtin\ Hynek/doktor.txt | awk   'END{print $i"-"$h,"\t",NR}'

done
```

Comment: Unless there is more to your input file those numbers appear to be column/field `$2` and not `$3` as you have in your awk script. You should also be more specific about what exactly isn't working about your attempt (and what output you are getting rather than what you wanted to be getting).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This can be a way:

```
awk '{d=int($2)
      a[d]++
      if (NR==1) {min=d}
      min=(min>=d?d:min)
      max=(max>d?max:d)}
      END{for (i=min; i<=max; i++) print i, "-", i+1, a[i]+0}' file
```

#### Explanation

Keep track of appearances in array `a[]` and then loop through the indexes in between `min` and `max`.

- `d=int($2)` get the integer part of the number.
- `a[d]++` increment number of appearances of this field on array.
- `if (NR==1) {min=d}` set minimum on the first line.
- `min=(min>=d?d:min)` update the minimum.
- `max=(max>d?max:d)}` update the maximum.
- `END{for (i=min; i<=max; i++) print i, "-", i+1, a[i]+0}` loop through the indexes printing the appearances. If no value was found, prints 0 as per the `+0` trick ([thanks Jaypal!](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23889143/grouping-with-condition-awk#comment36782789_23889292)).

#### Test

```
$ awk '{d=int($2); a[d]++; if (NR==1) {min=d}; min=(min>=d?d:min); max=(max>d?max:d)} END{for (i=min; i<=max; i++) print i, "-", i+1, a[i]+0}' file
30 - 31 2
31 - 32 2
32 - 33 0
33 - 34 1
34 - 35 1
```

Comment: Isn't the definition of `int()` "give you the integer part of the number"? Why the math? Is setting min necessary? It will be assumed to be zero the first time you use it, no?

Comment: Oh yes you are right. I was playing with integer division and couldn't manage to get the integer part, then I discovered the `int()` but somehow I kept the math. Regarding the min, that is the problem: as default is `0`, it won't ever be stored because the other fields have values bigger than `30`. That's why I store the first value as min and then keep comparing.

Comment: Ah, right, wasn't thinking about the point of min there. Sorry.

Comment: Nice! though `(a[i]?a[i]:0)` can be written as `a[i]+0`.

Comment: Ok good one @jaypal, I am adding this into my answer. Many thanks!!

Answer (score 4):

Perl solution:

```
perl -ane '
        $h{ int $F[1] }++
    }{
        print "$_ - ", $_ + 1, "\t", $h{$_}, "\n"
            for sort { $a <=> $b } keys %h
'
```

To get the zero lines, you can add `min` and `max` from [List::Util](http://p3rl.org/List%3a%3aUtil):

```
perl -MList::Util=min,max -ane '
        $h{ int $F[1] }++
    }{
        print "$_ - ", $_ + 1, "\t", 0 + $h{$_}, "\n"
            for min(keys %h) .. max(keys %h);
'
```

Comment: For those (myself included), who are wondering what is **`}{`**, it is called [Eskimo greeting](http://search.cpan.org/~book/perlsecret-1.008/lib/perlsecret.pod#Eskimo_greeting)

Comment: Nice solution @choroba. Though it doesn't print the range with `0` elements. For eg. `32 - 33 0` mainly due to the fact that key does not exist in our hash. I have an [ugly fix](http://ideone.com/P343du). Would like to see your approach though!

Comment: @choroba Thanks for the edit. That indeed is a better approach. I was able to make my ugly fix less ugly by doing what you did here `print "$_ - ", $_ + 1, "\t", $h{$_}+0 for $a[0] .. $a[-1]` but wasn't happy coz I had to create a separate array just to get the min max. Was hoping to make use of the keys for iteration but never around it.

Answer (score 1):

My solution:

```
awk '{print $2}' file.txt | sed 's/\..*//' | sort | uniq -c | awk '{print $2, $1}'  > counts.txt
paste <(seq 30 34) <(seq 31 35) | join -a1 - counts.txt  | awk '!$3{$3=0}{print $1 "-" $2 " " $3}'
```